# Redux's combineReducers and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-form, react-intl

I'd like to use `react-intl-redux` and `redux-form` in my react app but I have a trouble doing the right thing while using `combineReducers`. I've tried many things but still couldn't figure it out.

**react-intl-redux**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { intlReducer, IntlState } from "react-intl-redux";

export interface IAppState {
  intl: IntlState;
}

export default combineReducers<IAppState>({
  intl: intlReducer
});
```

> [ts] Argument of type '{ intl: (state: IntlState, action: IntlAction)
>   => IntlState; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject'.   Types of property 'intl'
>   are incompatible.
>       Type '(state: IntlState, action: IntlAction) => IntlState' is not assignable to type 'Reducer'.
>         Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
>           Type 'IntlState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IntlState'.
>             Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IntlState'. (alias) function intlReducer(state: IntlState, action: IntlAction):
>   IntlState import intlReducer

**redux-form**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer, FormState } from "redux-form";

export interface IAppState {
  form: FormState;
}

export default combineReducers<IAppState>({
  form: formReducer
});
```

> [ts] Argument of type '{ form: FormReducer; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject'.   Types
>   of property 'form' are incompatible.
>       Type 'FormReducer' is not assignable to type 'Reducer'.
>         Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
>           Type 'FormState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormStateMap'.
>             Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormStateMap'. (alias) const formReducer: FormReducer import formReducer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CombineReducers with Typescript returns error "Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266283/combinereducers-with-typescript-returns-error-argument-of-type-is-not-assignabl)

Comment: I'm looking forward to see the typescript implementations of `react-intl-redux` and `redux-form` especially.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-intl-redux and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-form ?

Comment: Thanks @falinsky, I have all that. But I'd like to see an example code because I'm newbie in TypeScript field and couldn't figure out how to implement these two libraries. I have no problem with implementing my own reducers tho'.

Comment: did u solve the problem?

Comment: @funky-nd I switched to Flow for now :) I'll get back to TS when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

Try FormStateMap instead of FormState.